# Postgres create new table, maintaining primary key from existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table called 'spectrum' with a primary key (id), and full of data. Now, I need to create a new table called 'tag' with a foreign key from spectrum and a new column ('tag'), which must have null values.

The problem I'm facing is: when I create the new table, it appears all empty. I need to have the existing values of the foreign key in the new table

[Spectrum Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EATmb.png) 
[Tag Table (Now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g74Uz.png) 
[Tag Table (Should be)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0tR.png)

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual data. Copy and paste the table definitions as text into your question. 2) Show the code, again as text, that you are using now.

Comment: If you want rows in a new table, you have to `INSERT` them.